# for each MenuItem RemoveAt

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, menuitem

I developed a basic system in that loops through the menuitems in a menu collection on page load (items are hardcoded, so can't use rowdatabound event) and disables those that don't meet a certain user level criteria:

```
        For Each item As MenuItem In NavigationMenu.Items

            Dim value As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value)
            Dim level As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(Session.Item("uxID"))

            If value > level Then item.Enabled = False

        Next
```

It works great and disables all of the menuitems that it should and ignores the rest.  The catch is that as time has gone by the amount of menuitems has increased, and its difficult for some users to know what they do and don't have access to.

My understanding is that menuitems don't have a visible property, but can be removed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitemcollection.removeat.aspx) but I'm stumped on how to get the index of the menuitem in order to do so.

Comment: at what event would you like to get the index of menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the same:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0

While i < NavigationMenu.Items.Count
    Dim value As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(NavigationMenu.Items(i).Value)
    Dim level As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(Session.Item("uxID"))

    If value > level Then : NavigationMenu.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    Else : i += 1
    End If
End While
```

Keep in mind that you can **not** do a foreach and remove items inside, because you will get an Exception about modifying the array which is looping.